# Alexa Skill Kit - AudioPlayer Metadata Images

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to implement an audiostream (radio) with images to display on Alexa devices. The audio works fine, but for some reason my images stopped displaying after I tried to change the source image the first time. Not sure if I'm just messing up the syntax, or if it's something else entirely.

According to the doc the "audioItem.stream.token may be cached in the Alexa service for up to five days", which in term can affect image display. But changing the token to something new doesn't seem to do anything.

Hope somebody has some insight into this.

```
const radioStream = [
  {
    'token': '1',
    'url': 'https://url-to-stream/',
    'metadata': {
      "title": "title",
      "subtitle": "subtitle",
      "art": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "url": "https://url-to-image/image.png",
            "widthPixels": 512,
            "heightPixels": 512
          }
        ]
      },
      "backgroundImage": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "url": "https://url-to-image/image.png",
            "widthPixels": 1200,
            "heightPixels": 800
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
];
...
handle(handlerInput) {
    const stream = radioStream[0];
    handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(handlerInput.t('AFFIRMATION'))
      .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective('REPLACE_ALL', radioStream.url, radioStream.token, 0, null, radioStream.metadata);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .getResponse();
  },
```

Comment: On what device are you testing? It work fine with this config when I update it after I change the token multiple times.

Comment: On a Fire HD 8 Tablet (8. Gen)

Comment: Which OS Version? Is it the latest update? Have you tried on any other devices?

Comment: Fire OS 7.3.2.1
Haven't been able to try on any other devices yet. I'll see if I can get another one to test on..

Comment: You were right mate, a new Echo show displays the images correctly. Put it as an answer so I can give you the cred :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is correct.

The [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#images) confirm that you have to update the token to allow the metadata to be refreshed. I tested and It work properly.

Based on your comments, it seems that the issue persist on your Fire HD 8 Tablet with the Fire OS version `7.3.2.1`.

It's always a good practice to try on different devices to validate the root cause.

I recommend you to contact the developer directly on the [amazon developer forum](https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/index.html). They should be able to push a fix for the device and fireOS version.